# Algebraic manipulation of product of two summations

Tags: summation

If

$F_1(x)=\sum_{n\ge 0}a_nx^n$, $F_2(x)=\sum_{n\ge 0}b_nx^n$,

why does the following hold?

$$\begin{align*}
F_1(x)F_2'(x)&=\sum_{n\ge 0}a_nx^n\sum_{n\ge 0}nb_nx^{n-1}\\
&=\sum_{n\ge 0}a_nx^n\sum_{n\ge 0}(n+1)b_{n+1}x^n\\
&=\sum_{n\ge 0}\sum_{k=0}^na_k(n-k+1)b_{n-k+1}x^n
\end{align*}$$   More specifically, how does one move from the second to the third line of the derivative-related equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group the individual products *by increasing degree*. In more details:

- First rewrite the second line as
  $$\sum_{k\ge 0}a_kx^k\sum_{m\ge 0}(m+1)b_{m+1}x^m$$
  Pairwise products have the form $\,\,a_kx^k\cdot (m+1)b_{m+1}x^m =a_k(m+1)b_{m+1}x^{m+k}$.
- If this term has degree $n$, then $k+m=n$, so $m=n-k$. We have $0\le k,m\le n$. Just group all possible terms of degree $n$; you obtain:
  $$\sum_{k= 0}^na_k(n_k+1)b_{n-k+1}x^n.$$